# Command for resolving ip address for host entry in /etc/hosts?

Tags: dns, hosts

I'm looking for a command that will let me resolve a host name in `/etc/hosts` to its corresponding IP address.

`nslookup` ignores entries in `/etc/hosts` file.

`ping` will find entries in `/etc/hosts` but is difficult/slow to capture the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS you can use [`dscacheutil`](https://ss64.com/osx/dscacheutil.html), the Directory Service Cache Utility, for this purpose.

```
dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost
```

The output looks like:

```
name: localhost
ipv6_address: ::1

name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

(On Linux, the equivalent is [`getent`](https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-using-etc-hosts-first).)